# Kendo UI Grid popup edit

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using latest KendoUI version. How I can customize popup window in kendo ui grid? (editable: "popup" in table options). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> editable: {
>       mode: "popup",
>       template: kendo.template($("#popup_editor").html()) }

Answer (score 0):

For customize popup window in Kendo UI Grid, you can use `editable` property of Grid:

```js
editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    template: kendo.template($("#custom_editor").html())
}

----------------
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="custom_editor">
        <div class="k-edit-label required">UserName : </div>
        <input type="text" name="UserName" class="k-textbox">
        .....
    </script>
```

If you want to use **different popup editors in a Grid for the Create and Update** data operations, You should define a template for both of them :

```js
editable: {
    mode:"popup",
    template: $("#template").html()
},
```

and then define template like this :

```js
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
        #if(data.isNew()) {#
        #var createTemp = kendo.template($("\#createTemplate").html());#
        #=createTemp(data)#
        #} else {#
        #var editTemp = kendo.template($("\#editTemplate").html());#
        #=editTemp(data)#
        #}#
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="createTemplate">
        <div class="k-edit-label required">UserName : </div>
        <input type="text" name="UserName" class="k-textbox">
        .....
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="editTemplate">
        <div class="k-edit-label">UserName : </div>
        <input type="text" name="UserName" class="k-textbox" readonly="readonly">
        .....
    </script>
```