# Kendo Grid Separate Popup Window Title & Buttons for Create & Edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to change the title of the editable popup window based on whether it is being used to create or edit a grid item (I want the fields to be the same for both of them, though).

I have set the popup window's title in `editable`

```
editable: {
        mode: "popup",
        template: kendo.template($("#popupTemplate").html()),
        window: {
              title: "Add"
        }
  }
```

But I'm not sure how to differentiate between Edit and Add.  The Edit button is in the columns:

```
command: [
        {
              name: "edit",
              text: {
                    edit: "Edit",
                    update: "Save",
                    cancel: "Cancel"
              }
        }
]
```

and the Add button in the toolbar:

```
toolbar: [{name: 'create'}]
```

Notably, I've tried this to no avail:

```
toolbar: [
        {
              name: 'create',
              click: function(){
                    alert("test");
              }
        },
]
```

I've also seen `e.model.isNew()` used under `edit`, but according to my compiler, this is not a function.

I've looked all over the internet and Telerik and found nothing.  Am I missing something?

EDIT: Someone asked for the entirety of my grid code:

```
var grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
  //dataSource: this.source,
  dataSource: this.testData,
  height: 550,
  filterable: true,
  sortable: true,
  pageable: {
    pageSize: 30,
    buttonCount: 1
  },
  //toolbar: ["create", "destroy", "search"],
  toolbar: [
        {name: 'create'},
        {name: 'destroy'},
        {name: 'search'},
        {template: "<input id='category' type='search' style='width: 250px; float: right;'/>"}
  ],
  resizeable: true,
  columns: [
  {
    field: 'Name',
    title: 'Name',
    filterable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'MCN',
    title: 'P/N',
    filterable: false,
  },
  {
    field: 'ID',
    title: 'ID',
    filterable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'Type',
    title: 'Type',
    filterable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'Subtype',
    title: 'Subtype',
    filterable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'Value',
    title: 'Value',
    filterable: false,
  },
  {
    field: 'Tolerance',
    title: 'Tolerance',
    filterable: true, //Number/letter combination causes problem?
  },
  {
    command: [
        {
              name: "edit",
              text: {
                    edit: "Edit",
                    update: "Save",
                    cancel: "Cancel"
              }
        },
        {
              name: "copy",
              text: "Copy",
              //click: function 
        }
    ],
    title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px"
  },
  ],
  editable: {
        mode: "popup",
        template: kendo.template($("#popupTemplate").html()),
        // window: {
        //       title: "Add"
        // }
  },
  selectable: "multiple, row", // Select multiples by drag or Shift-Click
  edit: function(e){
        var container = e.container;
        var model = e.model;

        //console.log(model.get("ID"));

        // Changing the size of the container
        $(e.container).parent().css({
              //width: "1000px",
              //height: "500px"
        });

        //May be able to simplify this with a for loop
        // Changing Type input to a dropdown
        var input = $('#dropType');
        input.kendoDropDownList({
              dataTextField: "Type",
              dataValueField: "dropType",
              dataSource: [{Type: 'One'}, {Type: 'Two'}, {Type: 'Three'}],
        }).appendTo(container);

        // Changing Subtype input into a dropdown
        var input = $('#dropSubtype');
        input.kendoDropDownList({
              dataTextField: "Subtype",
              dataValueField: "dropSubtype",
              dataSource: [{Subtype: 'One'}, {Subtype: 'Two'}, {Subtype: 'Three'}],
        }).appendTo(container);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the `title` you should use `edit` function of the grid like this:

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {...},
    height: 550,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [
        {
            field: "",
            title: '',
            attributes: { style: "text-align:center;" },
            headerAttributes: { style: "text-align: center;" }
        },
        {
            command: [
                { name: "edit", text: 'Edit' },
            ],
            title: 'tools',
            width: "200px",
            attributes: { style: "text-align:center;" },
            headerAttributes: { style: "text-align: center;" }
        }
    ],
    editable: {
        mode: "popup",
        template: $("#template").html(),
    },
    edit: function(e) {
        if (e.model.isNew()) {
            e.container.kendoWindow("title", "Createee");
        } else {
            e.container.kendoWindow("title", "Updateee");
        }
    }

});
```

And for using the template, see this answer : [Kendo UI Grid popup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61308227/7894673)

---

**Edit:**
According to kendo : [Kendo Forum](https://www.telerik.com/forums/e-model-isnew()#boJ8sq6aG2OF1P8AAFTdxQ) , [isNew](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model/methods/isnew)

> The `isNew` method returns `true` or `false` depending on the `id` value of that model.
> If the `id` is still set to the default value then it will assume it is a New Model.

So I think your problem is because of your `dataSource`, and you should fill `id` before the `fields` property. like this :

```
dataSource: {
   transport: {
        read: {
            url: ...
            type: "POST", // The request type.
            dataType: "json", // The data type of the returned result.
        },
        create: {...},
        update: {...},
        destroy: {...}
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { editable: false },
                BankName: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                ....
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize: 20
},
```

And here are two Samples: ( [Sample 1](https://dojo.telerik.com/AzejEQaT) , [Sample 2](https://dojo.telerik.com/ERotepeX) )

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, `e.model.isNew()` is not being recognized as a function for me.  Thanks for the other code, though.

Comment: @NightTerror6 Could you please put your grid code completely?

Comment: Added to original post.

Comment: @NightTerror6 I edited my answer, please check it and tell me the result. Hope it works

Comment: Currently I'm using a simple array for my datasource, looks like that's what's causing the issue.  Thanks for the help.